# Standards for colour of conductors of pre-assembled cables

Tags: high-voltage, high-current, standard, cable-assemblies, colour-coding

We are designing a product for industrial energy storage systems. Multiple units are connected with pre-fabricated cable assemblies of 2-4 separate leads that are terminated in  connectors unique to our system, similar in concept to these:

[image: Molex Minifit connector]

Now, for branding purposes, we want to use our company‘s colours for the leads in these cables. Some of them conduct high voltage and current during use.

For now, we are looking to only sell this product in the EU.

I found a few norms regarding single leads and screw terminals in machine building, where only certain ways of marking cables are allowed, and standards for mains AC cabling, but nothing that explicitly talks about pre-fabricated cables.

How can I find out whether custom colouring of cables is allowed in the field our product will be used in?
Is this sort of thing maybe common practice in the industry?

Comment: Look at similar products with similar cable assemblies.

Comment: Could you add braiding to the cables, so that inside they are standard colours like black for 0 V, but the overall appeareance is that of the (possibly custom-made) braid?

Comment: AFAIK, color standards only apply when individual wires are going to be connected by the end user (e.g., consumers or electricians). For a cable assembly like this, there are no standards.

Comment: Render to Caesar the things that are Caesar's, and to God the things that are God's.  Color-coding the wires in company colors for branding purposes is a wrong design choice.  Find some other way to brand you cable assemblies, if that's important.

Comment: Pin 1, brown, Pin2 red. etc  - use the resistor colour code.

Comment: @AndrewMorton that would indeed be possible, but probably increase cost too much.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Could you explain why? If there's no functional use for the colour coding because you can't connect anything incorrectly, why is it wrong to colour the cables the way I want?